# $injector.get is causing the Angular module's run() method to be called every time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a need to manually get things from the angular $injector.

I've been going:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['app.service', 'ng']);
var myService = injector.get('myService');
```

This worked great. But I've since noticed a problem, the app.service module's `run()` method is being called everytime I call `angular.injector`. I had things in there which initialised my app, which are now being run too many times.

**Should I move my app bootstrapping logic out of the run() method, or is there another way to get the $injector without having the run() method called?**

I'm also a bit concerned calling the injector a lot is bad for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation may be unclear on that, but `angular.injector` indeed initiates the whole module with `config` and `run` blocks (otherwise you would run across the issues with app components that depend on these blocks).

The instances of module services (including `$rootScope`) also won't be the same as the ones within bootstrapped app.

You are free to divide the module the way its services would be easy to use, but keep in mind that you won't be able to interact with running Angular app. If you need to use the same code inside and outside Angular, then define it outside.

If you need to interact with running app instead, then do

```
var injector = angular.element(document).injector();
```

instead, as the documentation [suggests](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector#example).

> I'm also a bit concerned calling the injector a lot is bad for
>   performance?

Sure, there would be some RAM and CPU overhead , its severity totally depends on your module.